# File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation error while using web scraping through Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to programmatically click a button in a web page using the command

document.getElementsByName("versionFile")[0].click()

while this command works fine in the developer tool console (opens the file selector) i am not able to execute this in script because it gives me a error saying "File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation" highlighting the click() function

Can anyone hep me out with this.

Comment: What does vba have to do with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers restrict the JavaScript interactions not started by the user, to avoid annoying pages and make XSS a bit more difficult.

If you are using a web-scraping library like [`puppeteer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), you should interact with the page using it's API (using `page.click` for example), not by injecting JavaScript on the page.

If that is not a option, you need to find the callback function that the button fires, and bypass the `element.click()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As of latest years, this is no longer working :

Chrome shows for such operations :
[image]

No js can do this anymore

Comment: welp time for a workaround using the clipboard and pyautogui lol