# Oracle apex open file browser automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I need to open "File Browse" item ("P50_BLOB") on page load.
I tried clicking the item with dynamic action on page load with javascript:

```
$('#P50_BLOB').click();
```

it didn't work, though it does work using the console.

I have also tried using async / wait / promise / wait for document to load.
I even tried to do it with another apex item that will make that click when it is changed, and manually changing the item is working, but on page load it's not.

This is supposed to be very simple but nothing works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you try that with the developer tools open in Chrome you will see an error:
[image]

Googling that led to this SO question:

[File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation error while using web scraping through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70847950/18747)

Comment: Thank you, for some reason, I don't see that kind of warning in my devTools but now I understand why it's not working